# C Producer Consumer using semaphores

Tags: c, mutex, semaphore

Why does, for the first few iterations of the output from my code display the consumer consumes 0 twice, when it should consume the first two items produced?

```
Consumer consumes 0
Producer produces 17
Producer produces 17
Consumer consumes 0
Producer produces 10
Producer produces 12
Consumer consumes 10
Producer produces 11
Producer produces 43
Consumer consumes 12
Producer produces 33
Producer produces 39
Consumer consumes 11
```

here is some of my code for displaying

```
#define N 10

typedef int semaphore;
semaphore mutex, full, empty;

int first=0,last=0, semArray[N];
```

Could it the use of the global variables ?

```
int produce_item(){
    int item = rand()%50 +1;
    printf("Producer produces %d\n",item);
    sleep(1);
    return item;
}

void consume_item(int item){
    printf("Consumer consumes %d\n",item);
    sleep(2);
}

int remove_item(){  
    int temp = semArray[first];
    first = first +1;
    return temp;
}

void insert_item(int item){
    semArray[last] = item;
    last++;
}
```

This is the producer and consumer functions for semaphores

```
void* consumer(void* arg) {
    int item, i=0;
    while(1){
        down(full);
        down(mutex);
        item = remove_item();
        up(mutex);
        up(empty);
        consume_item(item);
    }
    return 0;
}

void* producer(void* arg) { 
    int item, i=0;
    while(1){
        item=produce_item();
        down(empty);
        down(mutex);
        insert_item(item);
        up(mutex);
        up(full);
    }
    return 0;
}

void down(semaphore s){
    setSemaphore(s,0,-1);   
}

void up(semaphore s){
    setSemaphore(s,0,1);
} 


int setSemaphore(int semID, int semNum, int semOp){
    struct sembuf Buf;
    Buf.sem_num = semNum;
    Buf.sem_op  = semOp;
    Buf.sem_flg = 0;
    return semop(semID,&Buf,1);
}
main() {
    int i;
    pthread_t threads[2];   
    srand(time(NULL));
    int semid_full, semid_empty, semid_mutex;

    key_t key;
    key = ftok("task2.c", 'J');

    //initialize and create each semaphore set 
    semid_empty = semget(key, 1, 0600|IPC_CREAT);
    arg.val = N; 
    semctl(semid_empty, 0, SETVAL, arg);
    semid_full = semget(key, 1, 0600|IPC_CREAT);
    arg.val = 0; 
    semctl(semid_empty, 0, SETVAL, arg);
    semid_mutex = semget(key, 1, 0600|IPC_CREAT);
    arg.val = 1; 
    semctl(semid_mutex, 0, SETVAL, arg);

       pthread_create(&threads[0],NULL,consumer,NULL);
    pthread_create(&threads[1],NULL,producer,NULL);
        //remove 
    semctl(semid_empty, 0 , IPC_RMID, arg);
    semctl(semid_full, 0, IPC_RMID,arg);
    semctl(semid_mutex, 0 , IPC_RMID, arg);
    for(i=0; i<2; i++) {
        pthread_join(threads[i],NULL);
    }
```

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE]. Your current example does not include a `main()` function, nor the implementations of `up()` and `down()` (which are extremely suspect, given the `typedef` for `semaphore`).

Answer (score 1):

There are a few obvious problems that need fixing before there is any hope that this code will work:

1. `semid_empty`, `semid_empty`, and `semid_empty` are the *same*
   semaphore set, and therefore all of the `semop()` operations are operating on the same semaphore.
2. The code removes the semaphore sets immediately
   after creating the producer and consumer threads. All subsequent
   calls to `semop()` made within those threads are failing.
3. When attempting to initialise `semid_full` to 0, the code
   incorrectly uses `semid_empty` as the semaphore id.

There are a few ways to fix item 1:

- Use a different key for each semaphore set or, since the semaphores
  are used only in the same process, you can simply use `IPC_PRIVATE`
  as the key, e.g.

  ```
  semid_empty = semget(IPC_PRIVATE, 1, 0600|IPC_CREAT);
  ```

  This will ensure that each semaphore set is unique.
- Create 3 semaphores in the same set and assign them roles as the
  empty semaphore, full semaphore and mutex semaphore. Reference the
  relevant semaphore by it's number in calls to `semop()`, `semctl`, etc.

To fix item 2:

- Don't remove the semaphores. The semaphores will be recreated or reused as necessary between executions of the program. All will be well provided that they are properly initialised each time, or
- Organise for the semaphores to be removed when the process exits. You
  might use signals or whatever other methods are available.

Item 3 is probably just a typo, fix it with:

```
semctl(semid_full, 0, SETVAL, arg);
```

Finally, and this is very important, **add error checking and logging** to your code; most of these problems would have been immediately apparent, especially the `semop()` failures in `setSemaphore()`. This would have led you to discover the problems for yourself.

I am not sure that fixing the above will fix all the code problems, or that your algorithm is even correct, but it's a start, and you can then try adding debug logging and error checking to solve any other lurking problems.